What is the time complexity of this algorithm for parallel merge sort
What is the time complexity of the below algorithm? We are using parallel programming and running inner loops in parallel. This is parallel algorithm of merge sort.
PARALLEL_MERGE_SORT
INPUT: n data elements, each on its own PEj , 1 ≤ j ≤ n.
OUTPUT: Sorted data such that PEj ≤ PEj+1 for 1 ≤ j ≤ n.
1 for i <- 1 to Ceiling(n/2)
2     for all PEj such that j is odd and 1 ≤ j <n
3         if PEj.a > PEj+1.a
4             swap(PEj.a, PE j+1.a)
5     for all PEj such that j is even and 1 ≤ j <n
6         if PEj.a > PEj+1.a
7             swap(PEj.a, PEj+1.a)

I think the complexity should be O(n^2) but I am not sure if it is correct.

Do you use a special parallel complexity definition? Otherwise the complexity is the same as if you do not use parallel execution.

Doesn't look like mege-sort to me. Looks more like Bubble-Sort.

Complexity of the code is O(n²) outer loop is run n/2 times and both inner looks also.

It seems the algorithm is meant to execute on an abstract machine like PRAM based on the input description ("each on its own PEj"). This is important as its changes the complexity. PRAM is an unrealistic model since it cannot be physically implemented (it would require an infinite amount of core and so an infinite amount of mater and energy while the amount is bounded in our observable universe). This is why the resulting complexity is also unrealistically small and different from the real-world one. Such information matters. Please share your university teaching course context.

@JérômeRichard yes this is correct. We are supposed to run this algo on parallel machine not a regular machine. Here is the complete question. I hope it provides the context required. -> What model or computation should we use? What is the time complexity of this algorithm? What is the speedup of this algorithm, compared to the non-parallel version? Does that make this work optimal? Work efficient?

This is not a context but additional questions (except the confirmation of the use of PRAM). Also please note that this is better to update the question if you want to add more information.

To help you on the initial question: the second loop is not a usual loop since it is executed in parallel on all PE. Thus, it should not be considered the same way when computing the complexity. You can analyse what a sigle PE does to better understand what happen and the resulting complexity on such a parallel abstract machine.

I don't think all PEj are running in parallel. In my unit I have another exmaple with pseudocode that has a loop which is running in parallel and its represented as (forall Pi do in parallel    // 1 ≤ i ≤ n; NOTE: this is not a for loop!) which is not the case in current algo. And also we are using EREW of PRAM for this specific problem as only one processing element PE should be able to read and write at a specific time.
